# How to convert a WinForm application in service application

Tags: .net, vb.net, service

I have a .NET Winform application ( I call it : MyApp ) which has a single purpose: run tasks at specific times.

Now, i need to convert or run this application as service.

So I think i've to add a Window Service project to my solution and.. simply run the second solution ( MyApp).

Can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any user interaction with your app or does it just sit there and do something when a `Timer` raises a `Tick` event or some such?  If you want to do things at specific times without user interaction then it is generally better to create a Console application and run it from using the Task Scheduler in Windows.  A service is generally there for other applications to interact with at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move logic/code which runs tasks at specific time to the third project - plain library without winforms or windows service or others.

Then you will be able to use this library in your Winforms application and same library in Windows service application.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not that simple. Windows Service is very different from classic Windows application - it have no user interface, no standard message loop and it must implement some basic methods - at least Start, Stop. If your Windows application is designed good (which I highly doubt, because in Windows Forms, you can't use MVVM to separate business logic and UI), you can use its business logic in that Windows service.

Comment: _because in Windows Forms, you can't use MVVM to separate business logic and UI_ - sorry, but MVVM perfectly fit into Winforms. Winforms supports data-binding, not so powerful as WPF, but still you will be able to separate business logic and UI. You even will be able to re-use viewmodels made for Winforms in WPF.

Comment: @Fabio I am afraid that it is not true. In pure MVVM application, there is absolutely no need to have code in Window (Form) class, which is impossible in WinForms. MVVM is about separating business and presentation layer.

Comment: You are right. Winform class is the view, and will contains only code related to the view(eventhandlers without business logic, but simply calling viewmodel's commands, data-binding). You will be able to create winforms with data-binding with designer only. You know that xaml will be compiled into c# code, winforms designer doing same thing in different way. So you will be able to separate view and business logic in Winforms too